# www.topstonesoftware.com is not forwarding to topstonesoftware.com on AWS static web site

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

I've been trying to follow the directions on the AWS page

[Example: Setting up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)

I have created two S3 buckets: topstonesoftware.com and www.topstonesoftware.com.  The www bucket forwards to the topstonesoftware.com bucket

I've made the Amazon Route 53 entries (see below).

For reasons that I don't understand, http://topstonesoftware.com works, but http://www.topstonesoftware.com doesn't work (e.g., entering www.topstonesoftware.com just hangs the browser and never resolves the DNS).

When I run "dig" (dig www.topstonesoftware.com) it reports that there is no error in the DNS lookup. Dig also shows the DNS query resolving to the S3 bucket for www.topstonesoftware.com:

```
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47363
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.topstonesoftware.com.  IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.topstonesoftware.com. 300   IN  CNAME   www.topstonesoftware.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.
www.topstonesoftware.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 60 IN CNAME s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.
s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 5 IN A  52.216.17.170
```

I've read thought Stackoverflow and the Amazon documentation, but so far, no joy.

Here's the DNS.  The alias record is for topstonesoftware.com and is the alias to the S3 bucket. The CNAME record details are shown.

[image: Route 53 Screen shot]

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your config looks fine me to and my I get redirected.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look and for the post, @imperalix.  As I commented below, it was not correct to include the CNAME record. There needs to be an alias record for topstonesoftware.com and for www.topstonesoftware.com. Each of these alias records points to the associated S3 bucket. Where I made a mistake was in the permissions for the www.topstonesoftware.com bucket. The www.topstonesoftware.com bucket should be created as public, but there should not be a JSON permission record included, as there is for the topstonesoftware.com bucket. When I made these changes, it started to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you review the AWS documentation from your link you will notice that the docs are using **Type A - ALIAS**. You are using a **CNAME**. Change your **www** entry to use **Type A - ALIAS** and select the correct S3 website endpoint. Sometimes it takes a minute or two to populate the drop down list.

Comment: Thanks for the note, John. I appreciate the reply. You're right, I should have used Alias records. As it turns out, there was another problem with the way I created the AWS S3 bucket www.topstonesoftware.com.  I used a permission record that was the same as the one I used for topstonesoftware.com. I should not have done this. I deleted the bucket and recreated it, with public permissions. Then I redirected it to topstonesoftware.com. I then added alias records, one for topstonesoftware.com and one for www.topstonesoftware.com.  After all of the DNS dust settled, it now works.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the www.example.com bucket that is paired with your example.com bucket on AWS S3, create the www.example.com bucket with public permissions. **Do not add the JSON permission record that you added for the example.com bucket.** For some reason, this messes up access.

When I removed my www.topstonesoftware.com bucket and recreated it with public permissions and added forwarding to topstonesoftware.com, the www.topstonesoftware.com subdomain started to work.

As noted above, a CNAME record is not needed and may, in fact, be counter productive.